# QMessageBox.setIcon() doesn't set the icon

Tags: python, pyqt4, qmessagebox

I'm writing a program using PyQt4 that shows a [`QMessageBox`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmessagebox.html) to give the user a warning. I'm trying to set a default icon using [`setIcon()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmessagebox.html#setIcon), but it doesn't show.

I'm using Python 2.7 and PyQt4 4.11.4.

Here's an example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMessageBox

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
msg = QMessageBox()
msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
msg.setText("Where is my icon?")
msg.exec_()
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

**EDIT:** as requested by @mata, here is my current output:

[image: output with no icon]

If I look for a specific image outside Qt, it works as expected:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMessageBox, QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
import urllib

url = 'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo1w.png'
data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
image = QImage()
image.loadFromData(data)
pixmap = QPixmap(image).scaledToHeight(32, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
msg = QMessageBox()
msg.setIconPixmap(pixmap)
msg.setText("There is an icon from the Internet here!")
msg.exec_()
```

And the output:

[image: output with an icon]

Comment: Do you mean the icon in the message box, or the window/taskbar icon? The former is set using `setIcon()`/`setIconPixmap()`, the latter using `setWindowIcon()`

Comment: I mean the icon in the message box.

Comment: Could be an icon theme problem... A screenshot of how it looks could be helpful. Does it work if you use something like `msg.setIconPixmap(QPixmap("/path/to/some/existing/image.png"))`?

Comment: I have edited my question with additional info.

Comment: I tried the code and I had no problems, try to reinstall PyQt.

Comment: Like I said, this looks like an icon theme problem. What does `QIcon.themeName()` show? There should be a theme with the same name (directory) in the one of the locations given by `QIcon.themeSearchPaths()`. If not you need to install that theme, or change the theme using `qtconfig`

Comment: @mata `QIcon.themeName()` returns an empty string and when I try `QIcon.themeSearchPaths()`, python crashes and I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: That can happen if you try to execute those methods without first initializing a `QApplication`, try after initializing it

Comment: `QIcon.themeName()` is `hicolor'.

Comment: `QIcon.themeSearchPaths()` is 
`['/usr/share/xubuntu/icons',
 '/usr/share/xfce4/icons',
 '/usr/local/share/icons',
 '/usr/share/icons',
 '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/icons',
 '/usr/share/icons',
 ':/icons']`
When I run `qtconfig` I get `qtconfig: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qtconfig': No such file or directory`.

Comment: Is the package `hicolor-icon-theme` installed? `qtconfig` should be in the package `qt4-qtconfig`

Comment: How can I find those two packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried with Python 3 and PyQt5, and it works. The code changes a bit:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
msg = QMessageBox()
msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
msg.setText("Where is my icon?")
msg.exec_()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In PyQt6 you need to use `msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Icon.Warning)`.